# django queryset excluding rows that are referenced in a foreign table

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Part of my app consists of displaying statuses at the top of the newsfeed. Here i have my Status model

```
class Status(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 600, blank = False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/statuspics/%Y/%m/%d', blank = True, null = True)
    utility = models.ForeignKey(Utility)
    numlikes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        # Change plural form
        verbose_name_plural = "statuses"
```

I then have responses, which is a way of indicating how a post was responded to, and the status that announces it.

```
class Response(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null = True, blank = True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, null = True, blank = True)
    status_level = models.IntegerField(
        blank = True,
        choices = STATUS_CHOICES,
        default = 1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, editable = False)
```

Basically what I want to do is display ONLY the statuses that don't have any responses corresponding with it. I think i need to use exclude() in my views but i'm not entirely sure how to use it properly in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `Status.objects.exclude(response__isnull=True)`? It's basically do reverse lookup on model `Status` on `Response`.

[Django doc about isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull).

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this (reverse look up)

```
Status.objects.filter(response__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not the way a Djangonaut would do it, but you can get the list of *statuses that don't have any responses* with :

`[s for s in Status.objects.all() if s not in [r.status for r in Response.objects.all()]]`

Comment: You definitely shouldn't do it this way... newer... ever!